# WPF round button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm-light

I'm trying to create a round button which has a border shown when hovering and has an object binded color.
I tried to make this but when thes button's color is other than transparent, I can't click on it. Could you help me pls ? I am new to wpf and don't understand everything about it.

```
 <Page.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="Stone">
        <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding}">

            <Border CornerRadius="15" Height="30" Width="30" Margin="0"  >
                <Button Content="{Binding}" Tag="{Binding Name}" Height="30" Width="30" Margin="0" Click="Button_Click" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StrColor}" Value="black">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StrColor}" Value="white">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StrColor}" Value="none">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Border.Style>
            </Border>             

        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>


    <DataTemplate x:Key="Goban">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding }" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource Stone}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
```

</Page.Resources>

```
<StackPanel Name="Goban">
    <ItemsControl  Height="570" Margin="20" x:Name="LstPlateau" ItemsSource="{Binding LstPlateau, Mode=Default}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource Goban}">
        <ItemsControl.Background>

            <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Pictures/goban19.png" Stretch="Fill" />
        </ItemsControl.Background>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

For more details, i'm using mvvm light and, when I click a transparent button, the command fire but it don't whith other color (breakpoint not reached in the command).
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Why are you writing "round button" but showing a rectangular button template and an unrelated style containing only a triggers?

Comment: I tried ro create round button using a border with 30 width and height  and a round corner radius of 15. It make a rectangle with just the round corners, so a circle. The button is inside the border and "invisible"

Comment: @rodolphejamin: Why would you be able to click on the button when the `Background` of the `Border` is `Transparent` but not when it is set to some other `Brush`? This makes no sense. How to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The button is inside the border and "invisible"

To get a round button (or another shape other than rectangular), you need to change the template of the button itself.

Here's an example of a FULL circular button template.
Record it in a resource dictionary and use it in your button.

I did not set color bindings, because I did not understand from your code where they are used.

```
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
       <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonRoundStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse"
                                     Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{Binding BorderThickness.Left, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}"
                                     Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            </Ellipse>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ellipse" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ellipse" Value="{DynamicResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ellipse" Value="{DynamicResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ellipse" Value="{DynamicResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ellipse" Value="{DynamicResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ellipse" Value="{DynamicResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ellipse" Value="{DynamicResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{DynamicResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

All keys are obtained through DynamicResource.
Therefore, they can be redefined at the place where the template is applied.

> I edited the question, in my project I try ...

After complementing the question with the complete XAML code, if I understood it correctly, the pattern I showed is applied like this:

```
    <Button  Content="{Binding}" Tag="{Binding Name}"
                Height="130" Width="130" Margin="0"
                Click="Button_Click">
        <Button.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="Gray"/>
        </Button.Resources>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonRoundStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StrColor}" Value="black">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StrColor}" Value="white">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding StrColor}" Value="none">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll rework it :)

Comment: From what I understand, you only need to set your data triggers to switch Background in the button at the place of its declaration.
Regular triggers for IsMouseOver - remove.

Comment: I also clarify, perhaps you do not know this.
`Transparent` sets the brush to transparent.
The transparency will also be if set to `null`, that is, if there is no brush.
But if there is no brush, then objects for which there is no brush will be "transparent" for mouse clicks.

Comment: So, if I put the button in a border , the border background will be above it and block the click ?

Comment: The final layout of the elements is not clear to me from your explanations.
It will be better if you show it in XAML.

Comment: I edited the question, in my project I try to create a Go game with dynamically generated button binded on a 2D array (which is translated by an observableCollection of observableCollection  in my code)

Comment: I supplemented my answer with an example of style usage.
But I'm not sure that I correctly understood what kind of result you need to get.
If the result of my example does not suit you, then supplement your question with the images of the button in various states you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! I was stucked on thes buttons for many days, you really help me (and i can understand what you do )  :D